# Any way to programmatically open a collapsed console group?

Tags: console

I use **console.groupCollapsed()** to hide functions I don't generally need to review, but may occasionally want to dig into. One downside of this is that if I use console.warn or console.error inside that collapsed group, I may not notice it or it may be very hard to find. So when I encounter an error, I would like to force the collapsed group open to make it easy to spot the warning/error.

Is there any way to use JS to force the current console group (or just all blindly) to open?

Some way to jump directly to warnings/errors in Chrome debugger? Filtering just to warnings/errors does not work, as they remain hidden inside collapsed groups.

Or perhaps some way to ***force Chrome debugger to open all groups at once***? <alt/option>-clicking an object shows all levels inside it, but there does not appear to be a similar command to open all groups in the console. This would be a simple and probably ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this currently, nor am I aware of any plans to introduce such functionality, mainly because I don't think enough developers are actively using the feature to enough of a degree to create demand for this.

You *can* achieve what you're trying to do, but you need to write your own logging library. First thing you'll need to do is override the `console` API. Here is an example of what I do:

```
const consoleInterceptorKeysStack: string[][] = [];
export function getCurrentlyInterceptedConsoleKeys () { return lastElement(consoleInterceptorKeysStack); }
export function interceptConsole (keys: string[] = ['trace', 'debug', 'log', 'info', 'warn', 'error']) {
  consoleInterceptorKeysStack.push(keys);
  const backup: any = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    const key = keys[i];
    const _log = console[key];
    backup[key] = _log;
    console[key] = (...args: any[]) => {
      const frame = getCurrentLogFrame();
      if (isUndefined(frame)) return _log(...args);
      frame.children.push({ type: 'console', key, args });
      frame.hasLogs = true;
      frame.expand = true;
      _log(...args);
    };
  }
  return function restoreConsole () {
    consoleInterceptorKeysStack.pop();
    for (const key in backup) {
      console[key] = backup[key];
    }
  };
}
```

You'll notice a reference to a function `getCurrentLogFrame()`. Your logging framework will require the use of a global array that represents an execution stack. When you make a call, push details of the call onto the stack. When you leave the call, pop the stack. As you can see, when logging to the console, I'm not immediately writing the logs to the console. Instead, I'm storing them in the stack I'm maintaining. Elsewhere in the framework, when I enter and leave calls, I'm augmenting the existing stack frames with references to stack frames for child calls that were made before I pop the child frame from the stack.

By the time the entire execution stack finishes, I've captured a complete log of everything that was called, who called it, what the return value was (if any), and so on. And at that time, I can then pass the root stack frame to a function that prints the entire stack out to the console, now with the full benefit of hindsight on every call that was made, allowing me to decide what the logs should actually look like. If deeper in the stack there was (for example) a `console.debug` statement or an error thrown, I can choose to use `console.group` instead of `console.groupCollapsed`. If there was a return value, I could print that as a tail argument of the `console.group` statement. The possibilities are fairly extensive. Here's a screenshot of what my console logs look like:

[image: Custom console logging]

Note that you will have to architect your application in a way that allows for logging to be deeply integrated into your code, otherwise your code will get very messy. I use a visitor pattern for this. I have a suite of standard interface types that do almost everything of significance in my system's architecture. Each interface method includes a `visitor` object, which has properties and methods for every interface type in use in my system. Rather than calling interface methods directly, I use the visitor to do it. I have a standard visitor implementation that simply forwards calls to interface methods directly (i.e. the visitor doesn't do anything much on its own), but I then have a subclassed visitor type that references my logging framework internally. For every call, it tells the logging framework that we're entering a new execution frame. It then calls the default visitor internally to make the actual call, and when the call returns, the visitor tells the logging framework to exit the current call (i.e. to pop the stack and finalize any references to child calls, etc.). By having different visitor types, it means you can use your slow, expensive, logging visitor in development, and your fast, forwarding-only, default visitor in production.